Inbuilt function in NonlinearModelFit
Can you please tell me about the inbuilt function in NonlinearModelFit? Is it related to least-square fit? If yes, please describe.
 NonlinearModelFit[dataset, 
   PP[a, b, c, d][i, 
    t], {{a, 0.5}, {b, 0.02}, {c, 0.02}, {d, 0.8}}, {i, t}] // Quiet```


Yes, NonlinearModelFit performs a least-square fit for the given model function.
